# How to make frameset tag open in the page

Tags: html

I have this as main page but I need the new pages to open in the whole tab, not in the frame. Is there any code to do that?

```
<frameset rows="9%,*%"noresize="noresize" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
  <frame src="title.html"noresize="noresize" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
  <frameset cols="10%,*%"noresize="noresize" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame src="sidebar.html"noresize="noresize" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame src="main.html"noresize="noresize" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a `target="_blank"` to your anchors? More about the [target attribute on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target).

Example:

```
<a href="http://goo.gl/aQZplR" target="_blank">External link</a>
```

*Side note:* using frames for your whole site is considered bad practice more info here: [Exactly WHY are Frames bad?](http://mattheerema.com/web-tech-design/2005/09/exactly-why-are-frames-bad/)

Comment: Actually it's not just bad practice, HTML5 no longer supports frame or frameset, only iframes. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144515/why-were-frames-deprecated-in-html5-but-not-iframes  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements @conordb Please consider using another solution